# Embedded YouTube video keep playing on closed container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I worked on a lightbox, a window opened by click an element over jquery.
Works well on pictures, but if i open a YouTube Video and play it, after close the window (display:none), the video keep playing in the background..
I used [this tutorial](http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Super-Simple-Modal-Popups-with-jQuery-CSS3-Transitions.html) for the lightbox.
The YouTube Video is embedded as iframe.

Close the window

```
    $(".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").click(function() {
      $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(".modal-overlay").remove();
      });
    });
```

How i can fix my problem ?

Comment: What is that? Please make a demo on jsFiddle.net or at least provide the proper code of the youtube iframe.

Comment: Sorry @zer00ne for that. There you go. https://jsfiddle.net/Ljmxj8ue/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1. enable the iframe API with `enablejsapi=1` and add an `id` to the iframe:

```
<iframe id="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MxMBueIjtv0?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Step 2. load the API and create a player using the id from step 1.  For this demo, I used `player` (probably a bad choice):

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  /* probably should tie into the `onReady` event,
     but for this demo's purpose it's unnecessary.
     the video will probably be ready by the time
     you get to the close button. */
  player = new YT.Player('player');
}
```

Step 3. call the `stopVideo` Function in your close model snippet:

```
$(".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").click(function() {
  player.stopVideo(); /* you can optionally also set the video back
                         at the beginning with `player.seekTo(0);` */
  $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(".modal-overlay").remove();
  });
});
```

Docs: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4f5dksj5/

Comment: Oh one thing. If i add more videos on the page, just the first stops. Because i would use just one id, it is possible ? (Or use a class ? Seems dont work)

Comment: Looks like you can pass a DOM element instead of an id as a string: http://jsfiddle.net/4f5dksj5/1/.  Just get the element with jQuery and use `.get(0)` to pass the DOM node itself.  e.g. `player = new YT.Player($('.some-class:first').get(0));`  `:first` is redundant here, but I left it in to show more complex queries being used.

Comment: Better example: http://jsfiddle.net/4f5dksj5/2/ (it uses "player" as a class rather than an ID)

Comment: I tried like in your example, the second video keep playing. http://jsfiddle.net/4f5dksj5/3/ I made a mistake ?

Comment: @user5441400 Sorry.  Had already gone off to bed.  Basically the original example stored the player in a global variable because it's easy to get to.  What you now need is for each player to be modal specific.  In the next demo, I stored the player in a jQuery data attribute object for `.modal-box`.  Now when the close button is clicked, the function finds its own player and stops that one. http://jsfiddle.net/4f5dksj5/4/

Comment: Thank you so much, you made my day. I tried to get working for so much hours... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for React

---

```
interface props {
  videoId: string;
}

function YoutubeEmbedded (props:Props) {
  const { videoId } = props;

  const pauseVideo = () => {
    // At the place of pauseVideo you can use "stopVideo", "playVideo"
    var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
    iframe?.contentWindow?.postMessage(
      '{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}',
      "*"
    );
  };

  const handleCloseBtnClick = () => {
    pauseVideo();
    setShowVideoModal(false);
  };

return(
  <iframe
    src={`https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/${videoId}?enablejsapi=1`}
    title="YouTube video player"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
    allowFullScreen={true}
    frameBorder={0}
  />

  <button
    onClick={handleCloseBtnClick}
  />
)}
```